# IE form values not visible in inputs, after submission with validation errors

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, validation

I have a very strange problem with form repopulation in Internet Explorer - as far as I can tell it's only this browser which is affected.

Basically, I have a registration form with some server side validation (my website is built using CodeIgniter). If the form fails validation, the user is presented with a list of the validation errors, and the form is repopulated with the posted data in order that they can correct it.

The problem is that in IE the form values are not visible in the browser - but they ARE there if I view the page source and also if I inspect the form input elements using the Developer tool?!

If I submit the form again, then my CI validation says the fields are empty - so the hidden (or invisible) values do not get submitted by IE a second time.

Any ideas what is going on here as it's got my stumped?

[Edit] Here is the simplified source code:

http://pastebin.com/T2WUQ8v2

The issue is pretty obvious in hindsight!

Comment: can you post the source please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an IE conditional statement at the top the page that is replacing all data within the input with the value of the `placeholder` attribute, which in this case is empty.